# using localStorage and to store a count read that count

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to set up localStorage to have when the button is clicked the number of times the background color has changed is stored there. I also need to be able to clear it at any given point in time, and finally When the document starts, or the page reloaded, access the count that was saved in the above step. If there is not any data – then this is the first time to the web site so there is no need to show the count.

I do not know where to put the localStorage to be able to grab the count, or how to set up the button to clear the localStorage, sorry folks I am very new at all of this and having a very hard time trying to learn this.  I am not looking for anyone to write code for me I am just looking for suggestions on what to do next

The code is below any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks all!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head> 
    <title> </title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var count = 0; 
      var interval; 

      function getRandom(num){ 
          return Math.floor(Math.random()*num); 
      } 

      function changeColor(){ 
          count ++; 

          var num1 = getRandom(255); 
          var num2 = getRandom(255); 
          var num3 = getRandom(255); 
          var col = "rgb("+num1+","+num2+","+num3+")"; 
          var div = document.getElementById( 'myDiv' );

          div.style.background = col; 
      }



      function stop() { 
          clearInterval(interval);

          alert('The background color has changed ' + count + ' times before you clicked me!'); 
      } 

      interval = setInterval("changeColor()", 2000);
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      .Div {
          position:absolute;
          width: 800px;
          height: 100px;
          z-index: 15;
          top: 50%;
          left: 15%;
          background: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="setInterval()">
    <div id="myDiv" class="Div">
      <input type="button" onClick="stop()", value="I like this color" align="absmiddle">
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: why not read a bit of localStorage first? 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: change "var count = 0;" to "var count = +localStorage.count || 0;", then make "count ++;" into "localStorage.count= ++count;" and add <input type=reset onclick='localStorage.count=0'> to the html

Comment: i have read about localStorage but somewhat feel like i am trying to read a foreign language (which i know it is), i wish i could find a tutor where I am but at this point I can't find one ... i do appreciate all the help i have gotten so far